# Function Returns #Value Error sometimes

Tags: vba, function, excel, excel-formula

This method is based on the following 3 steps algorithm :

> 1 - generate two uniform numbers on the [-1,1] interval that you will call U1 and U2
>
> 2 - calculate S = U1 ^2 + U2^2
>
> 3 - If  S < 1 the normal number is given by  U1 * square root (-2 ln (S)/S) otherwise go back to step 1 until S < 1.

Program this function in VB and give it the name BoxMuller.

This is the function I wrote based on above steps I am not sure whether it's correct or not because sometimes it returns #Value error

I pass following values to the function `=BoxMuller(Rand(),Rand())`

```
Function BoxMuller(U1 As Double, U2 As Double) As Double
Dim S As Double

Do
    U1 = WorksheetFunction.NormInv(U1, 0, 1)
    U2 = WorksheetFunction.NormInv(U2, 0, 1)
    S = U1 * U1 + U2 * U2
    
    If S < 1 Then
        BoxMuller = U1 * Sqr(-2 * Log(S) / S)
        Exit Function
    End If

Loop Until S < 1
End Function
```

is the `Loop Until S < 1` condition right because I think that maybe the real cause of the error.

Also tried the following :

```
Function BoxMuller() As Double
Dim S As Double
Dim U1 As Double
Dim U2 As Double
Do

U1 = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(-1, 1)
U2 = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(-1, 1)

    S = U1 * U1 + U2 * U2
    
    If S < 1 Then
        BoxMuller = U1 * Sqr(-2 * Log(S) / S)
        Exit Function
    End If

Loop
End Function
```

And Called `=BoxMuller()` Still #Value Error

Comment: Do you ever pass a negative value to Log(S)?

Comment: I don't think S will be negative because S is the sum of square of U1 and U2 so the square will always return positive numbers

Comment: Right right. Try a while wend instead of a loop like you're suggesting then

Comment: hmm maybe....    If S < 1 and S <> 0 Then ....

Comment: I mean... You also can't pass log(0) and if Rand gives you .0001 * .0001 you're starting to get to number sizes larger than double could hold?  I'd write a debug if statement to see if s is ever less than like .0001

Comment: @CodyG. looking at the first step of algorithm . Am I passing the value from the right interval like from -1 to 1 or from 0 to 1 ? Am I passing right values ?

Comment: @Santosh RAND() Returns an evenly distributed random real number greater than or equal to 0 and less than 1. So... Probably not. You'd need to pass 2*Rand-1

Comment: sry i was wrong. but i made a test, started with `BoxMuller(0.1, 0.2)`. The first `do...loop` produce `U1=-1.2815`. that wat goes wrong in the second 'do...loop'. The probability is now beyond [-1,1]

Comment: i think the problem is this line `U1 = WorksheetFunction.NormInv(U1, 0, 1)`, NormInv generates a value not a percentage. So you can't do feedback loop of `U1` this way. The same for `U2`. but i must say i don't really understand what this line for.

Comment: @KSSheon I am just try to implement the algorithm mentioned in the question think you can do it ?

Comment: yup sure, my suggested answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have made some adjust to the final output, The output is not standard distribution but distribution of sample, so multiply sigma then plus mu. Otherwise the function wouldn't require any input.

`Rnd` is the native VBA to generate random number, it always fall within (0, 1).

Instead of doing a `do...loop`, you can use `GoTo` so that you don't have to call `exit function` to end the loop.

`application.volatile` will ensure the function recalculates every time you hit press F9. Remove this if you don't it.

```
Function BoxMuller(mu As Double, sigma As Double) As Double
    Application.Volatile
    Dim U1 As Double, U2 As Double, S As Double

ReCalc:

    Randomize
    'U1 = Rnd 'this is not correct for the function, leaving it here for reference.
    'U2 = Rnd
    'U1 = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(-1, 1) 'this is wrong too, RandBetween only returns interger
    'U2 = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(-1, 1)
    U1 = Rnd * 2 - 1
    U2 = Rnd 'the BoxMuller formula don't require U2 to be negative.
    S = U1 * U1 + U2 * U2

    If S < 1 Then
        BoxMuller = U1 * Sqr(-2 * (Log(S) / S) * sigma + mu
    Else
        GoTo ReCalc
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: ah, i see ur second attempt, perhaps `U1 = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(-1, 1)` is more appropriate

Comment: Thanks for the help but Still it returns #Value Error.

Answer (score 2):

KS Sheon workflow is right

but

- WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(-1, 1) returns an integer between -1 and 1

  while VBA Rnd() function returns a random double between 0 and 1
- VBA Log() function actually returns natural logarithm

I post two solutions (BoxMuller1 and BoxMuller2) that, along with what above, only differs in coding style and both use recursive calls

```
Function BoxMuller1(mu As Double, sigma As Double) As Double
    Application.Volatile
    Dim U1 As Double, U2 As Double, S As Double

    Do While GetS(Rnd, Rnd, U1, U2, S) >=1
        Randomize
    Loop
    BoxMuller1 = U1 * Sqr(-2 * Log(S) / S) * sigma + mu

End Function

Function GetS(Rnd1 As Double, Rnd2 As Double, U1 As Double, U2 As Double, S As Double) As Double
    U1 = 2*Rnd1 - 1
    U2 = 2*Rnd2 - 1
    S = U1 * U1 + U2 * U2
    GetS = S
End Function




Function BoxMuller2(mu As Double, sigma As Double) As Double
    Application.Volatile
    Dim U1 As Double, U2 As Double, S As Double

    Randomize
    U1 = 2*Rnd -1
    U2 = 2*Rnd -1
    S = U1 * U1 + U2 * U2

    If S >= 1 Then
        BoxMuller2 = BoxMuller2(mu, sigma)
    Else
        BoxMuller2 = U1 * Sqr(-2 * Log(S) / S) * sigma + mu
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Haha yes u r right, i wasnt thinking. Btw U1 shud be allowed to be negative number i. e. (-1,1). Rnd only range within (0,1).

Comment: Yes recursive function is more elegant. But just don't want to confuse him.

Comment: corrected U1 and U2 setting: added "-1" to return doubles between -1 and 1